# Django - Get object with unicode primary key

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, model

I can not pick a department has a **MySQL** database using a **primary key CharField**. I get the following error:

> DoesNotExist: Department matching query does not exist.

I made tested by retrieving the primary key with `all()` and then re-injecting into the `get()` and it works. **But indicating directly the value that does not work:**

```
>>> dept = Department.objects.all()[43].pk
>>> print dept
Haute-Vienne
>>> print type(dept)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> test = unicode('Haute-Vienne')
>>> print test
Haute-Vienne
>>> print type(test)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print '---'
>>> dept1 = Department.objects.get(name=dept)
>>> print dept1
Haute-Vienne
>>> dept2 = Department.objects.get(name=test)
...
Department matching query does not exist.
```

Models.py:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    num_reg = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    num_depts = models.CharField(_(u'Department number'), max_length=3, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(_(u'Name'), max_length=255, primary_key=True, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pk
```

Comment: What is the result of `print dept == test`?

Comment: print dept == test return False

Comment: Which explains why test doesn't work; it's obviously not the same as the actual pk value, somehow. How about `print repr(dept)`?

Comment: `print repr(dept)` return `u'Haute-Vienne\r'`

Comment: So, there you are: the value in the database has a LF character - `\r` - at the end. You'll need to use the same value in your query; or, even better, make sure you strip the value before saving in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
dept2 = Department.objects.get(name=test)
```

Try:

```
dept2 = Department.objects.get(name=test.name)
```

Comment: I believe this is just going to give you "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'" given that `test` is just a unicode string.